# Excel VBA - Need to delete rows where cell values in column B where reference errors are populated

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a loop towards the bottom of my code that successfully loops through my data and clears out all rows where Column H = 0.

However, there are several cells in column B displaying `#REF!`. I would also like this loop to delete those rows in the same manner as it does the 0s in column H.

I think my issue is not knowing how to reference those types of errors. Treating `#REF!` like a string doesn't appear to be working.

Thank you!

```
Sub test()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim startCell As Range
Dim r As Integer

Set startCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row    '<~~ Not sure why, but do not use "Set" when defining lastRow
lastCol = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

For r = 1 To lastRow Step -1
    If currentSht.Cells(r, "H").Value = 0 Or currentSht.Cells(r, "B").Text = "#REF!" Then
    Rows(r).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next r

currentSht.Range(startCell, currentSht.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `IsError(currentSht.Cells(r, "B"))` instead.

Comment: also you can combine the delete rows to `Rows(r).Delete`

Comment: Instead of checking the `Value` property, check the `Text` property.  That should return the `#REF!` string.

Comment: That didn't work...the actual text in each cell reads... "=VLOOKUP(A926,#REF!,4,FALSE)"...the first part in parentheses is respective to that particular #REF! cell

Comment: I thought you wrote that the cell was displaying #REF!

Comment: @Ron - That is what I initially tried in my code above. It did not work...each cell only reads #REF! on the worksheet, but when you click on each individual #REF! cell, at the top of the workbook you find `=VLOOKUP(A926,#REF!,4,FALSE)`.

Comment: Please use the foolowing code fragment to take care of ref error ~On Error Resume Next
       Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
       rngError.Clear 
   End If~   Even Instr function can be used ~ If InStr(1, rangereference, "#REF!")

Comment: @AndyG  There must be something strange about your setup, because if `#REF!` is what shows in the cell (not in the formula bar), than the `.Text` property should return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem:

```
 For r = 1 To lastRow Step -1
```

Change that line to

```
For r = lastrow to 1 Step -1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
Sub Delete0()

Dim F As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim RngCount As Range


Set RngCount = ActiveSheet.Range("H:H")
Y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RngCount)

For F = Y To 1 Step -1

If IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("H" & F)) Then
ActiveSheet.Rows(F).EntireRow.Delete
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("H" & F).Value = 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Rows(F).EntireRow.Delete
End If


Next F

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, let me test that real quick.

Comment: @VBAPete I would not expect it to work.  The .Value property of that cell would be Error 2023